# XNA 3D RPG Programming Inheritance

Tags: animation, xna, game-development, fbx

i am kinda new to Advanced Game programming and I am working on a 3D RPG game. I exported character and equipment models seperately in fbx files. Currently i can make a character equip or unequip several armor-weapon pieces with keyboard input, but this is happening without any animations because i don't know much about animating characters yet.

The thing i am asking is: i got a character model and some equipment models. Should i add these item models on character model in programming environment or should i add them in the modelling application and export them all in one fbx file? Which method would be wiser and will ease my future animating work on these models?

Modelling in: 3ds Max
Programming in: XNA for Visual Studio

Comment: From a programmers perspective, I'd say apply them on the model, and hide/show each piece of armor accordingly. This way, when you make animations you'll also get stuff like breastplates actually animating along with the rest of the character. Although yes, you may want to export each piece of armor as a separate FBX file.

Answer (score 0):

Just think about the numbers as they increase:

If you make models of each player with each armor configuration, you get `players * armor models * armor slots` models. If you make one model for each player, and one model for each piece of armor and apply them programmatically, you get `players + armor pieces` models - that's a lot less when the numbers get high (addition vs. multiplication).

You should, however, add a simple mesh to each player model that roughly represents the armor, so you can animate it (and use code to hide it in-game / replace it with the actual chosen armor.)

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective and experience:

- You may have player and all its equipment models in one source file. Such approach greatly reduce chaos when you have dozens of source files.
- It is better to export player and equipment in differend FBX files (mainly because of memory consumption and poor scalability). Skinned models may be easily attached to skeleton in runtime.
- Though if your player have no big variety of equipment then you may export the whole set of models in to one FBX (because poor scalability in this case withstand the complexity of code required to maintain multiple FBX files).